# How to apply text object commands to one level upper?

Tags: vim

I have a template tag in my HTML like this:

```
<span>Hello, {{ customer.name| truncatewords: 1, "" | capitalize }}</span>
```

I want to cut the tag. If I use `da{` when cursor inside of the template tag, it looks like this:

```
<span>Hello, {}</span>
```

This is what I want:

```
<span>Hello, </span>
```

And the `{{ customer.name| truncatewords: 1, "" | capitalize }}` part must be yanked of course.

I tried `da{{` but it doesn't works. How I do this?

ps: I have problem with `y` `c` or `v` commands too of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a count before the text-object:

```
d2a{
```

or, in most cases, before the operator:

```
2da{
```

From `:help a{`:

```
a}                          *v_a}* *a}* *a{*
a{                          *v_aB* *v_a{* *aB*
aB          "a Block", select [count] Blocks, from "[count] [{" to
            the matching '}', including the '{' and '}' (see
            |[{|).
            When used in Visual mode it is made characterwise.
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer it's worth noting that if you're selecting objects with visual mode you can always repeat it to select the next level.  In your case, <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> would select the inner set of `{}`, but repeating <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> would expand this to include the outer set as well.